# How long will it take to get from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3 at Dubai airport?

Tags: dubai, dxb

I have a flight with Emirates and one of its partner airlines via the same booking. My incoming flight will land at Dubai Terminal 1 and I have a layover of 1 hour and 40 minutes. My outgoing flight is at Terminal 3. How much time do I need to get from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3?

Comment: Does ‘partner airline’ mean both legs are on the same booking (one PNR)? Terminals 1 and 3 are connected airside https://www.airport-dubai.net/terminals.php Walking shouldn’t take more than 20 minutes https://www.qantas.com/au/en/qantas-experience/at-the-airport/airport-guides/dubai-airport-guide.html

Comment: Yes, both legs are on the same booking

Answer (score 1):

If your landside then use the coach from T1 exit 3 to T3..

If airside that becomes tricky
u take a coach from T3 connection desk Kilo and then transport to transfer connection desk in T1 and vice versa

Comment: What do you mean by landslide and airside?

Comment: If airside mean where the gates are, can we walk from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3?

Comment: @user106563 ‘Airside’ means in the international area of the airport (the boundary of which is the security check, customs, passport control, etc). According to Quantas https://www.qantas.com/au/en/qantas-experience/at-the-airport/airport-guides/dubai-airport-guide.html the walk between T1 and T3 is around 20 mins

Comment: Thanks. We should be on airside. So the walk should be manageable.  This answer might not be correct since it says it's "tricky" to get from T1 to T3 airside

Comment: @user106563 "Landside" is the part of the terminal accessible by land - i.e. where you transfer to/from a ground-based transport of some sort (car, bus, train, etc.). "Airside" is the part of the terminal that gives you access to aircraft. They are separated by the security screening area (at all airports) and (at international airports/international terminals) by customs & immigration.